# What is an alternative to InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider in hibernate 4.3.6

Tags: hibernate, datasource, c3p0

I used this class InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider for inject for multitenancy in hibernate 4.3 but in new version it is removed

```
InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider defaultProvider = new  InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider();
defaultProvider.setDataSource(cpds);     
return (ConnectionProvider) defaultProvider;
```

where cpds was conf of c3p0 , so can any one help me to get new one, Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl` instead of `InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider`.

Reference: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1034479

You can also refer to this `InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider` for better understanding.
https://github.com/ALRubinger/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-entitymanager/src/main/java/org/hibernate/ejb/connection/InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java

Even I was struck at the same point and I was able to resolve the issue using `DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl`.
Hope this helps.